# Prevent my app from running on devices other than currently released ones

Tags: ios, compatibility

Because my app sports a background that is made to fit the screen, I don't want my app to run on the devices for which the app has been made to run on. I am open to devices which have the same screen dimensions running the app but the app should not run on the ones with different screen proportions.

Comment: You should look at autolayout and UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

Answer (score 3):

You cannot enforce such a restriction. You must do exactly the opposite: make your interface adapt to any screen proportions.

That (as you've already been told in a comment) is exactly why there's auto layout — to help you with that task.

Comment: You can but not on the App Store. If its developer distributed or if its a corporate app they can.